# Кнопка free-kassa из PHP в Python

Tags: php, python, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем добрый день. Работаю с free-kassa. Free-kassa требует так называемую "кнопка free-kassa". Они даю код кнопки на PHP. Но пишу я на Python (пишу бота для телеграм, где бот отправляет сообщение - ссылку, по которой человек будет переходить на free-kassa и оплачивает товар). Подскажите, как этот код на PHP (кнопку) превратить в код на Python? Вот код кнопки: `<a href="//showstreams.tv/"><img src="//www.free-kassa.ru/img/fk_btn/13.png" title="Бесплатный видеохостинг"></a>`. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: У тебя есть картинка кнопки, ссылка и название. Т.е. нужно создать в боте кнопку с этой картинкой, которая будет кидать на ссылку

Comment: прежде чем получить ссылку, нужно активировать, а чтобы активировать (фиг знает что, на фри касе не разберешься), нужна эта кнопка. Вот такая работа у Free-kassa

Answer (score 0):

Это html код, а не php. Его надо вставить на страницу своего сайта.